# Возможно ли подключить JavaScript к конструктору Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Создаю свою тестовую карту через конструктор Google Maps.

Возможно ли как-то подключить к ней такие скрипты, что бы при добавлении определенного маркера вокруг него отображалась окружность, или же при наведении на маркер / клике на него в окне показывалась информация?

[image: Моя_карта]

Comment: Так ведь когда вы добавляете маркер то по дефолту можно добавлять информацию на него (заголовок и описание).

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk Информация появляется сбоку,а нужно что бы было сверху над маркером

Comment: Или же это делается не так. А нужно подключать все в стандартный каркас google Maps javascript API3.

Comment: как на меня лучше написать свою страницу и подключать карту с использованием google api. На своей странице точно можно будет манипулировать стилями маркеров и выводом информации используя javaScript.

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk а возможно как-то перенести все добавленные слои и маркеры на мою написанную карту?
Напиши мне свой ВК,я свяжусь с тобой.

Comment: насчет выгрузить в шейп инфу с гугл карты не знаю нужно читать документацию. https://vk.com/id419281513